# Generate Clang-tidy Report and attach to AzureDevOps pullrequest (yml pipeline)

Tags: azure-pipelines, clang-tidy

I have to Generate a Clang-tidy scan report and attach this report to the AzureDevOps Pull request. If there is no error this pull request can be accepted before merging it into the master branch.

I found nothing over the internet, any help or guideline in this regard will be extremely helpful.